# Uniform Spread of boolean values in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a bool vector such as:

```
vector<bool> bVec;
```

And I fill it with random 1's and 0's within a loop using pushbacks:

```
bVec.push_back(0);
bVec.push_back(1);
```

I can shuffle the contents:

```
random_shuffle(bVec.begin(), bVec.end());
```

Which works fine for a randomly shuffled vector, however, I if want uniformly distributed values I can't seem to get a proper vector.
ie I want to count the number of 1's and 0's and spread them out as uniformly as possible.  For example if I have 3 1's and 7 0's I would want something like
0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0 (or similar)

Writing my own function has proven to be fiddly and time consuming and prone to bugs.  Is there a function out there that I have not been able to find that will do this?

Thanks.

Comment: 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 on its own is not any less uniformly random than 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0. That's just humans being bad at judging "randomness".

Comment: That was just a sample, the real samples are often larger and when it isnt uniform it shows

Comment: How so? Can you predict any values or clusters? If not, "it shows" is most likely just your wrong sense of randomness. (Or shitty values from `rand`, but you'd probably still not detect that with the naked eye.)

Comment: 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 is not a uniform spread.  You wouldn't spread butter on the crust only on one side of your bread and eat it would you?

Comment: If you want to shuffle, 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 is just as likely as 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0. If you want to manually distribute the values according to some rules, state them.

Comment: You could generate a random number between 0 and the target size, then iterate forward over the vector setting that number of `1`'s uniformly

Comment: Uniform spread to me means having an equal number of distances between points wherever possible.  If you assume 1's are points 0's are not points then I guess it is spreading the points out with as much equal distance as possible, within a bool vector.  I don't know how else to describe it.

Comment: So your goal is to maximize the distance between non-zero values in a vector? By what metric do you want to do that? That is, what is the function `f(v)` over vectors `v` you want to maximize?

Comment: @DenizC we understand what "uniform" means, the problem is that you are sometimes using the word "random" in your description. Random and uniform are different things. If you want uniform spacing of 1s in your vector then it is not random generation of 1s and 0s.

Comment: I fill the vector randomly and then want to shuffle them into a uniform spread.

Comment: Either your definition of "shuffle" or of "uniform spread" is way off.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone gets to this and needs an answer (instead of arguing about semantics like in the comments above) I solved the problem as follows, step by step explained in pseudocode:

1) create a vector, randomly shuffle values in, count the 1's and use that as a desired amount and then set it all back to 0's.  Now you have a desired number of 1's as a target to spread uniformly within the vector.
2) Use a C++ implementation of matlabs linspace function (a few variations can be found here: https://gist.github.com/jmbr/2375233).  When you enter how many 1's you want and the size of the vector it returns equidistant points that you can round down to create indexes in your vector.
3) Set those points as 1's.

The result is a perfectly spaced vector.